# Is it possible to apply restrictions to several methods in C#

Tags: c#, restrictions

I have a script as follow :

```
Int MethodOne (int param) {
    If (param > 5) {
        Return 0;
    }
    Return param;
}

Int MethodTwo (int param) {
    If (param > 5) {
        Return 0;
    }
    Return param * anotherVariable;
}
```

Is it possible to apply the conditional 'method should not execute if param > 5' to all my methods without rewriting it inside every method?

Comment: I was just wondering if it is possible to avoid code repetition in this case

Comment: upvoting because people are downvoting without commenting to help the user improve the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is not to pass an int (see [primitive obsession](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrimitiveObsession))

```
public class NotMoreThanFive 
{
  public int Value {get; private set;}
  public NotMoreThanFive(int value) 
  {
    Value = value > 5 ? 0 : value;
  }
}
```

now

```
Int MethodOne (NotMoreThanFive param) {
    Return param.Value;
}

Int MethodTwo (NotMoreThanFive param) {
    Return param.Value * anotherVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way of doing what OP asked, so here is the best answer I could come up with. One way could be to create another `Restriction()` method so you can change it once and not in every method.

```
bool Restriction(int param)
{
    return param <= 5;
}

int MethodOne(int param)
{
    return Restriction(param) ? param : 0;
}

int MethodTwo(int param) 
{
    return Restriction(param) ? param * anotherVariable : 0;
}
```

Comment: And how this satisfy the condition _without rewriting it inside every method_?

Comment: Well, it doesn't. But I don't know a way of doing what OP asked, so I tried to give the best answer I could come up with.

Comment: I agree with you, but your comment should be added at the beginning of your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use Function.

```
Func<int,int> restrict = x => x <= 5 ? x : 0;

int MethodOne (int param) {
    return restrict(param);
}
int MethodTwo (int param) {
    return restrict(param) * anotherVariable;
}
//...
```

And when you just do `restrict(param)` it will do that check for you and will return desired number.

Comment: `int MethodThree(int param) { return anotherVariable / restrict(param); }` will crash badly.

Comment: @ArthurRey it will crash in anyway when you try to divide by `0`. and OP should be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing multiple methods, just write one method that takes a parameter to decide which functionality it needs to call and put your condition at the top of that method:

```
Int MethodOne (int func, int param) {
    If (param > 5) {
        Return 0;
    }

    switch(func)
    {
        case 1: Return param; break;
        case 2: Return param * anotherVariable; break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate int restriction(int x, string methodName);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = MethodOne(6);
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            int x1 = MethodOne(4);
            Console.WriteLine(x1);

            int x2 = Methodtwo(6);
            Console.WriteLine(x2);

            int x3 = Methodtwo(4);
            Console.WriteLine(x3);



            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int restrictionMethod(int param, string methodName)
        {
            if (param > 5)
            {
                param = 0;              

            }
            if (methodName == "MethodOne")
            {
                return param;
            }
            else if (methodName == "Methodtwo")
            {
                return param * 4;
            }

            return -1;
        }

        public static int MethodOne(int param) 
       {
           restriction rx = restrictionMethod;
           int returnValue = rx(param, "MethodOne");
           return returnValue;
       }

        public static int Methodtwo(int param)
       {
           restriction rx = restrictionMethod;
           int returnValue = rx(param, "Methodtwo");

           return returnValue;
       }


    }
}
```